# How to generate functions from an API spec

Tags: api, rest, specifications, ipaas

I am very interested in Integration Platform as a Service.
As we know, it is possible to generate an API spec from an API. Is the opposite possible?
I want to write a piece of software that automatically create some functions for calling the endpoints of an Open API. In order to achieve that, the piece of software should consume an API spec and generate the code. Theoretically, this could be possible, if the spec covers all endpoints with all parameters of the API, etc. but:

1. this is often not the case
2. specs are written differently from each other

My question is: what should my software consume in order to get reliable information about the API endpoints, parameters etc.? Is there a standard for that? Is the API spec the way to go?

Answer (score 0):

Look at Github Copilot. They're able to generate pretty descent facsimiles of functions from API spec. Just a word of caution, the function might not be 100% accurate and so you'll still need to check over it.

Answer (score 0):

In a properly designed webservice there are at least 4 layers, presentation, application, domain and infrastructure.
[image]

REST documentation describes only the presentation layer's outer surface: HTTP interface and operations, so it is not possible to generate a complete webservice based on the REST API documentation. If your application does not have any kind of logic, it is just a data structure and CRUD, then it is possible, but in that case you'd better to find a database which has a REST API and very good access control and problem solved mostly.

If you have some sort of standard documentation like WADL or JSON-LD with Hydra, then you can generate a REST API skeleton for the presentation. I just googled the topic a little bit, maybe this thesis can be useful for you: https://repositorio.ul.pt/bitstream/10451/35311/1/ulfc121800_tm_Telmo_Santos.pdf